# Kotlin traits and retrofit

Tags: retrofit, kotlin

I'm trying to implement the example from [here](http://howrobotswork.wordpress.com/2013/10/28/using-rxjava-in-android/) in Kotlin. I get this error at runtime "Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Interface definitions must not extend other interfaces". Is there any way to treat Kotlin traits as java interfaces when they don't have any methods implemented, or do I have to use java interfaces? Here's the code:

```
public trait RestAPI {

    [GET("/weather")]
    fun getList([Query("q")] place: String,
                [Query("units")] units: String)
            : Observable<WeatherData>
}
```

And the call that causes the error:

```
val service = restAdapter?.create(javaClass<RestAPI>())
```

Comment: Discussed is Kotlin's issue tracker: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-5609

Comment: @user1202036 can you please review the answer below and accept it if it is accurate.  Kotlin renamed `trait` to `interface` and changed the semantics somewhat.   And the issue mentioned by @andrey above was resolved.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue has been fixed. I am using Retrofit implemented exactly this way with Kotlin version 0.9.976.